# cake php webservice to display recursive data

Tags: web-services, cakephp, recursion

I have table with self_join
menus

```
id | menu_id | title | content
1    0        main1    
2    0        main2    
3    1        sub_1a   content
4    1        sub_1b   
5    4        sub_4a   
6    5        sub_5a
7    6        sub_6a   content
-------------------------------
I have 2 main menus with menu_id = 0  
main1(id=1) has 2 sub menus with id 3 and 4  
sub_1b(id=4) has 1 sub menu with id 5
sub_4a(id=5) has 1 sub menu with id 6
sub_5a(id=6) has 1 sub menu with id 7
this can be upto 5 levels
```

I have to display json recursive array
I have tried custom function in controller

```
public function menuz($id,$arr)
     {
   $arr[]=$id;
       $id=$id-1;
   if($id>0)
       {
          menuz($id,$arr);
       }
     }
```

I have called above function from index action
but it is giving error
what will be best aproach

Comment: you are calling menuz function from index but what menuz is returning?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  The recursive function you wrote doesn't really make sense to me as all it will do is add decreasing numbers into an array, and you could just as easily do that in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cakephp then attach [Tree](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html) behavior to your model (you'll have to add a couple of columns to your table, too)

then you can do

```
$data = $this->YourModel->find('threaded');
```

(see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded) abour it) to obtain a nested array that you can easily transform in json